# Xamarin.Forms customize listview style to zigzag

Tags: listview, xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin-studio

My purpose is to create a listview with the orientation like

cell1    cell2

cell3    cell4

cell5    cell6

cell7    cell8

by default each cell takes the entire width of listview, now I want to change it like zigzag, each cell is a viewcell(which each can bind to an item in a list individually). In order to do that I think I need to find where listview line up it's cell and change its way.

Is there any idea about this?

Comment: You are probably looking for `GridView`, which you tell to layout as two columns. Anyways, you are indirectly asking for a tutorial, which doesn't fit well on StackOverflow. Hence I am marking your question to be closed.

Answer (score 0):

I the same situation I end up creating custom `GridItemsView<T>` by extending `Grid` with `DataTemplate`.
Here is a hint for you:

```
    var columns = new ColumnDefinitionCollection();

    for (int i = 0; i < columnsCount; i++)
    {
        columns.Add(new ColumnDefinition());
    }

    SetValue(ColumnDefinitionsProperty, columns);

    int rowsCount = (itemsCount - 1) / columnsCount + 1;

    var rows = new RowDefinitionCollection();

    for (int i = 0; i < rowsCount; i++)
    {
        rows.Add(new RowDefinition());
    }

    SetValue(RowDefinitionsProperty, rows);
```

And:

```
    int col = 0;
    int row = 0;

    foreach (T item in items)
    {
        View child = (View) Template.CreateContent();
        child.BindingContext = item;

        child.SetValue(Grid.RowProperty, row);
        child.SetValue(Grid.ColumnProperty, col);

        col++;

        if (col == this.columnsCount)
        {
            col = 0;
            row++;
        }

        if (index >= 0)
        {
            Children.Insert(index++, child);
        }
        else
        {
            Children.Add(child);
        }
    }
```